# Error instantiating JSONObject from Map: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, json

I'm getting an error while using the **JSONObject** in `Java`.

I'm trying to instantiate a **JSONObject** from a `Map`:

```
Collection<Faction> factions = FactionColl.get().getAll();

        for(Faction f : factions) {
            String fac_id = f.getId();

            ResultSet count = this.db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM helu_fac WHERE fac_id='" + fac_id + "'");
            int exist = 0;
            while(count.next()) {
                exist = count.getInt("count");
            }

            if(exist == 0) {
                Connection conn = this.db.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO helu_fac VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                statement.setInt(1, 0);
                statement.setString(2, fac_id);
                statement.setString(3, f.getName().toLowerCase());
                statement.setString(4, f.getDescription());
                statement.setString(5, new JSONObject(f.getRelationWishes()).toJSONString());
                statement.setDouble(6, f.getPower());
                statement.setInt(7, 1);

                statement.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();
            } else {

                Connection conn = this.db.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE helu_fac SET "
                        + "fac_id = ?,"
                        + "name = ?,"
                        + "description = ?,"
                        + "relations = ?,"
                        + "power = ?"
                        + " WHERE fac_id =  \"" + fac_id +"\"");
                    ps.setString(1, f.getId());
                    ps.setString(2, f.getName().toLowerCase());
                    ps.setString(3, f.getDescription());
                    ps.setString(4, new JSONObject(f.getRelationWishes()).toJSONString());
                    ps.setString(5, String.valueOf(f.getPower()));

                    ps.executeUpdate();

                    conn.close();
            }

        }
```

and i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.simple.JSONObject: method <init>(Ljava/util/Map;)V not found
```

I searched everywhere, but i'm still getting this error.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `Map mymap;` is a null reference, other than that the error must lie elsewhere. Can you give more code? (i.e. fresh code, not just this patch)

Comment: what are the types of key & value of `mymap`

Comment: If you make sure your map is not null, try map.toString() instead map only.

Comment: When i'm trying do to map.toString(), eclipse tell me that the constructor JSONObject(String) is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells you, `org.json.simple.JSONObject` does not have a constructor which accepts a `Map` as the only parameter.

Perhaps you were meaning to use `org.json.JSONObject`, which does have such a constructor?

Check which `JSONObject` you have imported at the top of the class.